# Is this problem P or NP?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-hard, np

Given a set of whole numbers $M=\{z_0, ..., z_n\}$ Are there $z_i$ and $z_j$ with $i \neq j$ but $z_i = z_j$?

Is this Problem (surely or only probably) in $P$ or in $NP$? Is it $NP-hard$?

Comment: First of all, $M$ can't be a set if there might be equal elements in it. So you probably mean "sequence" rather than "set". Secondly, why not just check all pairs for equality? Or better yet - sort them and then check?

Comment: @Shaull Ok, but in what time and with which algorithm? Is it possible in polynomial time? I think the checking would be in polynomial time (if not then it is NP-hard), but what about the solving?

Comment: Assuming thee numbers are given in binary, then it would take $n^2$ comparisons, with each comparison taking $O(|<z_i>|)$ operations, which is polynomial in the size of the input.

Comment: @Shaull what more precisely means $O(|<z_i>|)$ operations?

Comment: The size of the description of $z_i$. Think of if this way: you have an array of elements, how complicated is to see if there are two equivalent elements in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *element distinctness* problem, and can be solved in polynomial time in many ways. For example, you can go over all pairs of elements and compare them, or if the elements are comparable, you can sort them and then check for duplicate elements (though in principle comparisons could be very time consuming, and in that case potentially the algorithms wouldn't be polynomial time; there's no such problem with the former algorithm).

Make sure you understand what "polynomial time" is. Also, you have a false dichotomy in your title: every problem in P is also in NP; if P=NP then every problem in P is also NP-complete; and if P≠NP then there are problems which are neither in P nor NP-hard.